# Read file from another package - Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, package

I'm trying to access a file from another package:
    -Using LoadDatabase from Main package to access DB.txt from resources.

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6zGF.png)

When I do

```
File file = new File("/com/Convocatoria/resources/DB.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
```

It gives me this error

> Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: You don't access a file from a package, you do it from the file system so your path must be a properly formatted path to a file on disk or you must use a class loader to read it as a resource.

Comment: which class contains the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Don't Use absolute path use getResourceAsStream method
I dont know which IDE you are using if you specify the path like this it jvm will look for file from the root of your project but your file is precent in your rootproject->src->**under some packages** so it is best to use getResouceAsStream because when you build it or run it all the .class files and property files will go under the class path so we know that our file will be in classpath So we can easily read the file using getResourceAsStream for eg:-
you are reading the file from MainWindow.java class
use the below code
InputStream is =MainWindow.class.getResourceAsStream("/Convocatoria/resources/DB.txt")
from this inputstream you use FileInputStream or whatever you want to read the file

Comment: Actually i tried that and it didn't work. System.out.println(is) gives me null

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading data from within your classpath, you can use resources instead:

```
String resourceName = "/com/Convocatoria/resources/DB.txt";
URL res = LoadDatabase.class.getResource(resourceName);
System.out.println("resource found at url="+res);
InputStream is = LoadDatabase.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
Scanner s = new Scanner(is);
//read..
//after using it, close your stream
is.close();
```

Comment: You need to elaborate on what resources are or provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

`File` constructor will throw a `FileNotFoundException` when it fails to find the file with specific path. You need to surround it with a `try-catch` block that catches the mentioned exception:

```
File file = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try{
    file = new File("/com/Convocatoria/resources/DB.txt");
    sc = new Scanner(file);

    // do something with opened file
} catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```